# What could break /proc/self/exe?

Tags: linux, system-calls

I have a simple Go program that calls `os.Executable()`. On older Linux systems (2.6.32), it cannot read `/proc/self/exe`, as showed by `strace -f myexe -v public_html/ |& head -30`:

```
execve("/home/willem/myexe", ["myexe", "-v", "public_html/"], [/* 45 vars */]) = 0
mmap(0x1200000, 13352277, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0) = 0x1200000
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/hom/willem/my"..., 4096) = 37
mmap(0x400000, 13463552, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x400000
mmap(0x400000, 10254571, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x400000
mprotect(0x400000, 10254571, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC) = 0
mmap(0xfc7000, 938770, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0x9c7000) = 0xfc7000
mprotect(0xfc7000, 938770, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mmap(0x10ad000, 170408, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x10ad000
munmap(0x1201000, 13348181)             = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="sip5-83.nexcess.net", ...}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x10d7000
brk(0x10d81c0)                          = 0x10d81c0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x10d7880)      = 0
set_tid_address(0x10d7b50)              = 16193
set_robust_list(0x10d7b60, 24)          = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x83c310, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x83ba20}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x83c3a0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x83ba20}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=10240*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/exe", 0x7ffcfec64dc0, 4096) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I don't understand why the first readlink works and the second does not. There's no fork and the executable is not moved. Any ideas?

I can fix it by moving the `os.Executable()` into the init of my program, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the cause turned out to be [UPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPX) (executable compressor). I hadn't thought of it earlier because it was included in my build pipeline. Apparently, on some systems it doesn't extract to memory but uses a temp file, which caused this error. Am still puzzled why the trace output doesn't show a rename, but alas.